# Custom webpack config alias not working in ionic 2

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, webpack, ionic2, alias

I am using environment alias in my custom config like this:
package.json

```
 "config": {
    "ionic_bundler": "webpack",
    "ionic_webpack": "./config/webpack-extension.config.js"
  }
```

webpack-extension.config.js

```
/*
inspired by:
    https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-app-scripts/pull/683#issuecomment-287401855
*/

let path = require('path')
let useDefaultConfig = require('@ionic/app-scripts/config/webpack.config.js')

module.exports = function () {

useDefaultConfig.resolve.alias = {
    "@app/env": path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/environments/env.' + process.env.IONIC_ENV + '.ts'),
};

return useDefaultConfig;
}
```

environment.ts

```
import {

isDEV,
API_HOST,
...etc

} from '@app/env'
```

But I am getting error:

```
Typescript Error
Cannot find module '@app/env'.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After hard googling I have found this fix (let typescript loader know the alias):
tsconfig.json

```
  "compilerOptions": {
...
    "baseUrl":  "./src",
    "paths": {
      "@app/config": ["config/config"]
    }
  }
...
```

credit: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-app-scripts/pull/683#issuecomment-294078919

My ionic info:

```
cli packages: (/Users/.../node_modules)

@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova       : 1.6.2
@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.4.1
@ionic/cli-utils                : 1.7.0
ionic (Ionic CLI)               : 3.7.0
```

global packages:

```
Cordova CLI : 7.0.1
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 2.1.3
Cordova Platforms  : none
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.6.0
```

System:

```
Node       : v6.9.5
OS         : macOS Sierra
Xcode      : Xcode 8.3.3 Build version 8E3004b 
ios-deploy : 1.9.1 
ios-sim    : 5.0.13 
npm        : 5.3.0
```